# How to draw two references from one class to another in a UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Imagine the following case: I have a class Method and a class DataType. A method has one return type (if we count void as a return type) and zero to many parameters. Both the return type and the parameters are instances of the class DataType.

How would I model this Situation in a UML class diagram? One line for two references or one for each?

**Solution A, one line:**
[image: Solution A: one line]

**Solution B, two lines:**
[image: Solution B: two lines]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to use role names instead:

[image]

Role names are explicit attributes in the opposite class, telling how the specific class is used. So `Method.parameter` is of type `DataType`.

Note that I changed the `return type` to be `0..1` rather than `1` since your text tells that it's optional.

Comment: Can I keep the arrows while using role names? Or should I stick to simple lines?

Comment: @JimL. Indeed. However, navigability has quite narrow semantics and the role names show that in much better way.

Comment: Data types are identified by their values, so they should not have even unnamed properties that reference classes. Those should be non-navigable or association owned.

Comment: @JimL. I did not ask about the model here as such. There's just too much context missing to argue in any direction.